# Правильный экспорт из localstorage

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Есть таблица на странице `index.html`, в каждой строке которой есть `checkbox`. По нажатию на чекбокс удаляется текущая строка и загружается в localstorage. При переходе на страницу `done.html`, содержащую идентичную таблицу, должны загружаться строки из localstorage (именно те, которые были удалены по чекбоксу). Если строка одна, то более менее понятно как оно должно хранится. Но как хранить и выгружать данные из хранилища, если я отмечу несколько строк? Примерно должно получится как-то так:
1. Захожу в `index.html`
2. Жму на чекбокс
3. Строка удаляется и записывается в хранилище
3. Иду на `done.html`
4. По `onload` загружается из хранилища ранее сохраненная строка
5. Иду опять на `index.html`
6. Отмечаю еще один чекбокс
7. Перезаписываю в хранилище обновленные данные уже с двумя строками ( тут по идее мы получаем то что в хранилище уже есть, добавляем вновь удаленную строку к уже существующим данным и кладем обратно в хранилище)
8. Иду на `done.html`
9. Вижу уже эти 2 строки

Надеюсь вопрос понятен, если что, задавайте уточняющие вопросы.

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';
  checkbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(event)');

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'image';
  btnEdit.className = 'btnEdit';
  btnEdit.src = 'icons/edit.png';
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btnDelete';
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdNum = document.createElement("td");
  tdNum.setAttribute("id", "td1_id");
  tdNum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var tdDone = document.createElement("td");
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdQuant = document.createElement("td");
  tdQuant.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdNum);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML);
}

function editButton() {
  localStorage.setItem('DoneList', document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML);
}

function delButton(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
  localStorage.setItem('DeleteList', document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}

function deletedLS() {
  var DeleteList = localStorage.getItem('DeleteList');
  if (DeleteList !== null) {
    document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = DeleteList;
  }

}

function doneLS() {
  var DoneList = localStorage.getItem('DoneList');
  if (DoneList !== null) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = DoneList;
  }
}

function indexLS() {
  var ShoppingList = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList');
  if (ShoppingList !== null) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = ShoppingList;
  }
}


function deleteRow(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 530px;
}

.main {
  background: #E9ECEF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 250px;
}

.table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 250px;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.li_index {
  background: #007BFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
}

.li_done {
  background: #007BFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
}

.li_del {
  background: #007BFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
}

.li {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
}

.hr {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px
}

.h1 {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.inputs {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 700;
}

.input_add {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  width: 230px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.input_quant {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.input_price {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.input_button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.tr {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.body {
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
}

.mytable {
  width: 700px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #007BFF;
}

.link_index {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.link_done {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.link_del {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
// INDEX.HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Shopping List</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/shortcut_add.ico" />
</head>

<body onload="indexLS();return false;" class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>



// DONE.HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Done Items</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/shortcut_done.ico" />
</head>

<body onload="doneLS();return false;" class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li_done"><a class="link_done" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Done Items</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Помогите реализовать это на практике. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteRow(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
  var shoppingList = { items: [] };
  var text = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList');
  if (text)
    shoppingList = JSON.parse(text);
  shoppingList.items.push(elCheck.outerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', JSON.stringify(shoppingList)); 
}
```

Comment: если честно, не очень понял( Я рассуждаю следующим образом: Когда я жму чекбокс я кладу эту строку в хранилище с ключом "DoneList", перехожу на done.html и из хранилища подгружается эта строка. Если я  снова в index.html нажимаю чекбокс на другой строке - ключ "DoneList" должен перезаписаться, а точнее дополнится записью - еще одной строкой... как-то так...